# Default page for a router

Tags: wifi, homepage

I wast to redirect a computers browser to a page on my server when they first connect, smiler to a hotel. I have a `DLINK DIR-615 WIRELESS N 300 ROUTER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always experiment with custom firmware like [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com). in itself it does not provide functionality you are looking for but it can be used together with [chillspot](http://www.chillispot.info/) to capture http traffic, redirect it to captivity portal and authenticate the users.